# Android: efficient way to update ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, refresh

I've got a `ViewPager` containing 5 `Fragments`, each containing 1 `ListView`, which contain some data I downloaded.
I'm making an refresh method now and to update the data the `ListView`s display, I'm just recalling the code I used to set it up the way I did in my `onCreate()`-method, which is this way:

```
mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
```

Where my `mSectionsPagerAdapter` looks like this:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        return MyFragment.newInstance(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "Title";
    }
}
```

But I bet there's a more efficient way of updating the ViewPager than just recreating it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

That is already the efficient way to create fragments. The fragment manager will cache the fragments for you. It will call `getItem()` only if the fragment has been destroyed, so you won't have to worry about it.

On the other hand, if you think your fragments will consume relatively large amount of memory, consider using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` instead.